# How to - Go Dynamic with PHP

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, if-statement, control-structure

I have a form which actions against a php file. Once the form is completed and the data is inserted into the databse, it want it to display "Awesome". Awesome is being displayed but is above the form. I want it to replace the form and display awesome. How do i do that?

Thank You.

```
if($done )
{
    echo "Awesome";
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you have something along the lines of:

```
if (condition) {
    Awesome
} 
The Form
```

Change it to

```
if (condition) {
    Awesome
} else {
    The Form
}
```

Comment: I want it to replace the form and display awesome.

Comment: @Johnson don't waste time to ask if you can't understand answer.

Comment: David, although your code is correct in general, there will be a redirect in real life.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to say @col.shrapnel

Comment: the form is never going into the else part...i don't want it to....

Comment: This is my result ....   Grab >> Input button ..once pressed, awesome is displayed above grab....i want it to replace grab

Comment: @Johnson why not? what's wrong with else part? Anyway, you'd better forget that useless "awesome" at all. Just redirect user to see entered data.

Answer (score 8):

You can make wonders with the [`if/else` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

Comment: thanks for the link, but that is not my question. Can i replace the msg with the input button, instead of having to display the msg on top of the button?

Comment: @Johnson: The code you showed us doesn't even show any input button. And it doesn't have any indication of what $done represents or where it came from.

Comment: that's just the part....i'll post the rest

Comment: $done is passing the php query

Comment: once the if condition is made true, awesome is displayed but above the input button.i want it to replace the button and display awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are overwhelmed with structuring your code in a way that gives the desired result, then you should take advantage of PHPs `include()` capability. Put your form in a second file, then rewrite your result logic:

```
if($done )
{
    echo "Awesome";
    include("form.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Or wherever you want the form to appear.